# relative path not work with credentials.Certificate()

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

I use Firebase in my python project. To initialize the credential.Certificate() I want to use a relative path like so:

```
cred_path = 'jsonfile.json'
cred_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),cred_path)
```

the output is

> C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\Rewrite\jsonfile.json

if I pass the path to the firebase method and convert it to an .exe with pyinstaller I get an error.

```
 cred = credentials.Certificate(m)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL' : 'databaseurl.com'
})
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "rewriteword.py", line 24,
> in    File "firebase_admin\credentials.py", line 82, in
> **init** FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'jsonfile.json' [18292]
> Failed to execute script testscript

If I am using the absolute path it works perfectly with no error. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I had to add the .json data to pyinstaller.

```
cred_path = 'jsonfile.json'
bundle_dir = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)))
path_to_dat = path.abspath(path.join(bundle_dir, cred_path))
```

> ```
> pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "jsonfile.json;." rewriteword.py
> ```